# I am looking for software to scan and read receipts

Tags: software, receipt

What are people using to scan and archive receipts?

The only software I've found that does this is NeatReceipts.  Does anyone recommend it? 
http://www.frys.com/product/5734692?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NeatReceipts come up from time to time on woot.com.   You can read up on the discussions which typically include several user testimonials at these past sales:

- [August 23, 2010](http://www.woot.com/Forums/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=4109089)
- [March 3, 2010](http://www.woot.com/forums/viewpost.aspx?postid=3821661)
- [May 21, 2009](http://sellout.woot.com/Forums/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=3223828)

Comment: The software is kind of clunky, but the hardware works great.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following apps/services:

- [EverNote](https://evernote.com/) with [Receipts](https://appcenter.evernote.com/app/receipts/iphone) app (image recognition makes finding receipts a snap),
- [Receipt Bank](http://www.receipt-bank.com/) (paid service, gathers paper receipts, scans them and processes the data),

  I've tested it, and it recognizing receipts very well, taking picture is very quick and easy, then you can upload the expenses into your accounting software by a click or automatically (e.g. FreeAgent), however the service it's a bit expensive. They've apps for Android and iPhone.
- [Expentory](https://expentory.com/) (app and cloud-based service for capturing expense receipts on the move),
- [Xpenditure](http://www.xpenditure.com/) (take picture of your receipt, and it can process it),
- [Kagazz](http://www.kagazz.com/) (integrates with FreeAgent and automatically uploads data and images from receipts and invoices into FreeAgent in real time),
- [Scan Tailor](http://scantailor.org/) ([at GitHub](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor)), an interactive post-processing tool for scanned pages.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning receipts is easy and any decent scanner will do a good job for you. The difficult part is the software that 'extracts' the data. Today there is no software that can do this really well because there is just too great a range of receipts (e.g. handwritten receipts, receipts in foreign languages, etc.). For this reason services like Shoeboxed (in the US) and Receipt Bank (in Europe) are very popular.

*(Added disclosure: Michael Wood's profile web site link indicates he is associated with Receipt Bank.)*

Comment: Hi Michael.  Welcome to the site!  I've added some disclosure to your answer.  It's a good idea to indicate directly in your answer any affiliation with a product or service being mentioned.

Comment: Chris - thanks. I thought I put a signature on the post for disclosure. Apologies if I didn't.